# Generate random numbers without repeat

Tags: vb.net

I've seen lots of tutorials, but it seems none works for me. I need to generate random numbers without repeating.

This is my code:

```
Dim intNumber As Integer
    Dim arrNumber(0 To 0) As Integer
    Dim i, x, y As Integer
    'Make sure the Label is clear
    Label1.Text = ""



    For x = 0 To 0
Start:
        intNumber = Int((25 * Rnd()) + 1) ' Random number 1 to 25
        For y = 0 To 0
            ' Check arrNumber (y)
            'If intnumber has already been selected,
            'Then go and select another one.
            If intNumber = arrNumber(y) Then
                GoTo Start
            End If
        Next y

        'Place the next non-repeated number in the arrNumber(x).

        arrNumber(x) = intNumber


    Next x

    '----------------------------------------------------
    For i = 0 To 0

        Label1.Text = Label1.Text & (arrNumber(i))
        broj1.random.Text = Label1.Text
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Without seeing the code, I can only guess that you are initialising the random number generator more than once, which will result in the same numbers being generated.

Comment: sorry i edited post i insert the code that i used before

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. Are you looking for the numbers 1 to 25 in a random order? Please understand it's inherent in randomness that sometimes numbers repeat. Look up the "birthday paradox."

Comment: <twitch>  Are you *sure* this is VB.NET?

Comment: I need this: On every click on the Button to get Number From 1 to 25 (JUST ONE NUMBER), in each click Number to be different from before

Comment: Bradley If is not VB.NET then what is? Maybe C++

Comment: @BradleyUffner : Infact that is valid VB.NET code. VB.NET is backwards compatible with many VB6 functionalities.

Comment: @AceDuk : I don't know if you were sarcastic there, but it's definitely _**not**_ C++.

Comment: I know that is not C++, It's vb.net, I have written in the title that is VB.NET

Comment: @O.Jones any solution?

Comment: Your `for` loops go from 0 to 0, which means they only repeat once. Your array has only 1 position, too, and you are creating a new array every time you click the button, which means no values will be ever saved. Solution? Start with simpler, more basic stuff. Learn how loops and arrays work, learn about variable scopes, and then you would understand what's wrong with your own code.

Comment: but I need quickly to solve the problem, I know that is not a solution, but ..

Comment: You have _**tagged it**_ vb.net. I removed "VB.NET" from the title because any languages, platforms, APIs, etc. belong in the tags **only**. Read more here: [**Should questions include "tags" in their titles?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: @VisualVincent ok :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, especially in vb, hard to solve. You're looking for a random *deal* rather than a random *roll.* That is, you're looking for an emulation of a casino dealer taking cards from a shuffled deck of 25 cards one by one, rather than a dealer spinning a 25-slot roulette wheel.

One thing that makes it hard is the 26th card dealt.  Reshuffle? Deal in same order?

Here's a decent essay on the topic. https://web.archive.org/web/20211020114009/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070208-1.aspx

Here's some C# code to deal.

```
    private static List<int> _deck = null;
    private static readonly Random NumberGenerator  = new Random();
    public static int Deal()
    {
        if (_deck == null || _deck.Count == 0)
        {
            /* new deck */
            _deck = new List<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i <= 24; i++) _deck.Add(i);
        }

        /* get a random card from the remaining deck */
        var next = NumberGenerator.Next(0, _deck.Count);
        /* retrieve the card's number */
        var q = _deck[next];
        /* and remove the card from the deck */
        _deck.RemoveAt(next);
        /* return in range 1-25 */
        return q + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to learn how to build the clock, sometimes you just need to know the time:

```
    Const HowMany As Integer = 25     ' how many numbers do you want?

    Dim Used As New List(Of Integer)
    Used.Add(0)                       ' position zero has 0, all other positions have a generated counting number

    For i = 1 To HowMany
        Dim OK As Boolean = False     ' OK becomes true when a unique number has been generated
        Do
            Dim num As Integer = Int((HowMany * Rnd()) + 1)
            If Used.Contains(num) Then
                OK = False         ' we'll try again shortly
            Else
                OK = True          ' this round is complete -- found a unique number
                Used.Add(num)      ' add the generated number to the list
            End If
        Loop Until OK     ' in other words, loop until we've found a unique number
    Next

    For i = 1 To HowMany
        MsgBox(Used(i))   ' or just use the list in however you need
    Next
```

Comment: Suggestion: When you have a fixed series like this example it is more efficient to just use Dim Used(25) as Boolean, and test/set the indexed values. Though that is nullified in this case since he wants to dump them after the fact.

Comment: Absolutely.  For a small number of values, the efficiency won't matter much, and for a simple demo I went with one list, instead of an array of booleans plus a list/array of results.  But when the number of values desired gets big, testing for `Used(986) = True` is going to be far faster than having the `Used.Contains` code check many hundreds of elements for this particular value.

Comment: So the code if work can i use that for more labels? Array of labels?

Comment: Also if i edit (For i = 25 to HowMany), will i get from 25-50 right?

Comment: Your results are in the `Used` list -- you can put those into whatever else you like.  Or put the results into your array of labels at the same time that the code is putting them into `Used`.  (Just don't stop putting them into `Used` because that's how the check for a unique value is performed.)

Comment: `For i = 25 to HowMany` with HowMany still being 25, is the same as `For i = 25 to 25` and that would only execute once.  If you want random numbers between 25 and 50, then you'll need further modification -- a lower number and an upper number, with HowMany being the difference between the two (plus one).

Comment: So i need to edit: (HowMany as integer = 50) and (For i = 25 to HowMany) and numbers will be between 25 and 50 right?

Comment: Dim num as Integer = Int((HowMany * Rnd())+ 24) like this? Thank you friends for helping me

Comment: Several problems.  You are creating 26 values, not 25, it should be `CInt` to convert to integer - not `Int`. And that is 3-4 times slower than simply `Enumerable.Range(1, 25).OrderBy(Function(x) Rnd()).ToArray()`

Comment: Thank you friends i will try and if i stuck somewhere i will ask for help, thanks.